# Twitch API returning "Redirect URI does not match registered URI"

Tags: node.js, api, express, axios, twitch-api

I am having a weird issue where Twitch's API isn't recognizing that both, the redirect URI in my code and the URI I provided are the same.

The exact error is
`Parameter redirect_uri does not match registered URI`

On the Twitch API dashboard, I have two URI endpoints:
 `http://localhost:8888/auth/twitch/callback` and
 `http://localhost:8888/auth/twitch/`

I have both my Twitch AUTH API and my Express server code below.

**TWITCH API**

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const config = require('../config.js');

const router = express.Router();

const authBaseURL = `https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2`;
const redirect_uri = `/auth/twitch/callback`; //${config.TWITCH_CLIENT_REDIR_HOST}

const authenticationAPI = axios.create({
    baseURL: authBaseURL,
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const qs = new URLSearchParams({
        client_id: config.TWITCH_CLIENT_ID,
        redirect_uri,
        response_type: 'code',
        scope: req.query.scope,
    });

    const redirectUrl = `${authBaseURL}/authorize?${qs}`;

    res.redirect(redirectUrl);
});

router.get('/callback', async (req, res) => {
    const { code, state } = req.query;

    const qs = new URLSearchParams({
        client_id: config.TWITCH_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: config.TWITCH_CLIENT_SECRET,
        code,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        redirect_uri,
    });

    try {
        const response = await authenticationAPI.post(`/token?${qs}`);
        res.json({
            expires_in: response.data.expires_in,
            scope: response.data.scope,
            token_type: response.data.token_type,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({
            message: error.message,
            body: error.response.data,
            // client_id: config.TWITCH_CLIENT_ID,
            // client_secret: config.TWITCH_CLIENT_SECRET,
            // client_redirect_host: config.TWITCH_CLIENT_REDIR_HOST,
        });
    }
});

module.exports = router;

// TEST URL - http://localhost:8888/auth/twitch?scope=chat:edit+chat:read+whispers:read
```

If you have a solution or any help you can provide, it is greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: it looks like the redirect uri you're sending to twitch is just `/auth/twitch/callback` rather than the whole uri `http://localhost:8888/auth/twitch/callback`?

Comment: I feel real stupid right now... thank you!